# Shifting array elements returns unexpected value

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I am programming for a STM32 ARM based board and I get the following problem:

I am moving elements inside an array but I get unexpected values that are not part of the array. Here is my code:

```
int temp=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2]=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[1];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[1]=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[0];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[0]=temp;
```

The values inside the array are (0,0,1) for example, so I expect to get (0,1,0) but, instead I get (224,1,0). This makes me suspect that some kind of garbage is being stored in temp, but I have tried initializing it to 0 when declared, getting the same result.

Also, using the same approach in a different part of the code works:

```
int temp=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[3];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[3]=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2]=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[1];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[1]=*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[0];
*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[0]=temp;
```

This shifts the values perfectly, so I can't understand why the first is not working and the second yes. Which could be the problem?

If it helps, I'm using Keil uVision 5 IDE.

PS: I know there are better ways to shift values in arrays, this is just a test I am doing.

**EDIT:** manual_items[] is an array of MANUAL_t, which is a struct I created. This is the struct:

```
typedef struct _manual_
{
  char Name[20];
  uint8_t *Byte_Control[4];
  STATUS_t *Status;
  status_type type;
  int Color_Ref;
  char Display_Ref[10];
} MANUAL_t;
```

So byte_control[] is of type uint8_t.

**EDIT 2:** This is the declartion of manual_items:

```
MANUAL_t manual_items[]=
{
  {"Barrier",{&BARRIERMAN},&status_items[3],UPDOWN,0,0},
  {"Sem. 1",{&SEM1GREENMAN,&SEM1YELLOWMAN,&SEM1REDMAN},&status_items[8],SEMAPHORE,0,0},
  {"Sem. 2",{&SEM2GREENMAN,&SEM2YELLOWMAN,&SEM2REDMAN},&status_items[9],SEMAPHORE,0,0}
};
```

**EDIT 3:** It finally works!! In the end the problem was not related to this piece of code, which is why I could not find what was causing the error. I had forgotten to put `break;`after two `switch case`s, which made the program go crazy. Thanks to all for your help and remember that mistakes are where you would expect the least!

Comment: It would help if you show the declaration and initialization of `manual_items`. In case you are unaware, `*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2]` means `manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2][0]`.  I wonder if you maybe meant `(*manual_items[select].Byte_Control)[2]` and so on.

Comment: What type is `*manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2]`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am quite new to C so probably the mistake has to do with what you are noting. Could you please explain the difference between `manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[2][0]` and  `(*manual_items[select].Byte_Control)[2]`?

Comment: @JavierGaztelumendi the second one is `manual_items[selec].Byte_Control[0][2]`.  Remember that `*X` always means `X[0]` in C.  To say which is correct, we would need to see how `Byte_Control` is declared and allocated.  So far you have shown its declaration, but what values are you storing in `manual_items[x].Byte_Control[0]` through `[3]` ?  (For example, pointers to some malloc'd space or what?)

Comment: Your last sentence should read `byte_control` is of type `uint8_t *[]`   .  It's an array of 4 elements, each of which points to a `uint8_t` stored elsewhere (which may or may not be the first in an array of `uint8_t`'s

Comment: I think you don't need to declare `uint8_t *Byte_Control[4]` into the structure `_manual_`. Where you allocate the memory for all element of `Byte_Control[4]`. I think you should use `uint8_t Byte_Control[4]!

Comment: @MattMcNabb `Byte_Control[0]` to `[3]` store pointers to uint8_t variables declared before, no malloc'd.

Comment: @JavierGaztelumendi Probably your pointers aren't pointing where you think, or `selec` is out of bounds. Check that theese "uint8_t variables" have not gone out of scope or something. It's hard to be any more specific without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In your example array you don't fill out all 4 values of `Byte_Control` ... so your code accessing `Byte_Control[3]` will dereference a null pointer

Comment: to add to @MattMcNabb, the third possibility(and in my opinion, most likely) is that the variables being pointed to are not all initialized.   We need to see more of the code to be sure of the root of the problem.

Comment: @user3629249 the initialization has been posted now

Comment: the initialization is only setting 3 of the 4 entries in Byte_Control[4].  So the 4th entry is trash.   The indications are that one of the 'address of' entries in Byte_Control is pointing to a variable that is not initialized

Comment: @user3629249 it is null pointer, not trash.

Comment: @user3629249  I understand what you say, but note that the 4th entry is not used in the first example, yet it doesn't work. I will try to fill the whole array just to see if I get something different. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ok, I just found that the error was on another part which had nothing to do with these code. Dumb me... Anyway, thank you for your help and patience with a newbie ;)

Comment: I think you should delete the question as it serves no community purpose since the problem is not what you thought and cannot be solved from the information given.  You really should have applied the debugger before posting the question perhaps?